# When I use User-defined Table Types in sqlserver It return -1

Tags: sql-server, transactions, user-defined-types

I have written following store Procedure. 
In Journal Table single Record will insert and in JournalDetail Multiple record will insert

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FINACCJournalInsert]
        @Date datetime
       ,@FiscalYearID int
       ,@PeriodID int
       ,@Memo varchar(500)
       ,@ProjectID varchar(128)
       ,@IsPost bit
       ,@IsVoid bit
       ,@Amount money
       ,@CurrencyCode varchar(3)
       ,@CurrencyID int
       ,@FINACCJournalDetailBulkInsert [FINACCJournalDetailBulkInsert] Readonly
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN TRY
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
Declare @JournalID as int

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FINACCJournal]
       ([Date],[FiscalYearID],[PeriodID],[Memo],[ProjectID],[IsPost],[IsVoid],[Amount],[CurrencyCode],[CurrencyID])
 VALUES
       (@Date,@FiscalYearID,@PeriodID,@Memo,@ProjectID,@IsPost,@IsVoid,@Amount,@CurrencyCode,@CurrencyID)

      set @JournalID = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 


      INSERT INTO [dbo].[FINACCJournalDetail]
       ([JournalID],[ReferenceID] ,[ReferenceNumber] ,[ReferenceCustomerVendorEmployeID]  ,[ReferenceCustomerVendorEmployeName] ,[Debit],[Credit])
       SELECT @JournalID, ReferenceID,ReferenceNumber,ReferenceCustomerVendorEmployeID,ReferenceCustomerVendorEmployeName,Debit,Credit From @FINACCJournalDetailBulkInsert
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
              ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
              ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
              ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
              ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
              ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        begin
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            return -2;
        end
    END CATCH;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    begin
        COMMIT TRANSACTION; 
        SELECT COUNT(*) [ID] FROM [FINACCJournal] WHERE ID = @JournalID
    end
 END
```

Below is code that how I am calling the store procedure

```
     public int InsertJournal(JournalModel model)
    {
        using (AccountingDataModelContainer1 contex = new AccountingDataModelContainer1())
        {                              
            using (AccountingDataModelContainer1 context = new AccountingDataModelContainer1())
            {
                DataTable table = model.AccountList.ToDataTable();
                SqlParameter[] sqlparameters = {                                                 
                                             new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Date",Value= model.Date,SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime},
                                             new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@FiscalYearID", Value=model.FiscalYearID,SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int},
                                             new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@PeriodID", Value=model.PeriodID, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int },
                                             new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Memo", Value=model.Memo,SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar},
                                             new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@ProjectID",Value=model.ProjectID ?? (object)DBNull.Value,SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar },
                                             new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@IsPost",Value= model.IsPost,SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Bit},
                                             new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@IsVoid", Value=model.IsVoid,SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Bit},
                                             new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Amount", Value=model.Amount, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Money },
                                             new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@CurrencyCode", Value=model.CurrencyCode,SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar},
                                             new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@CurrencyID",Value=model.CurrencyID,SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int},
                                             new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@FINACCJournalDetailBulkInsert",Value=table,SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured,TypeName="FINACCJournalDetailBulkInsert"}
                                           };
                int retval=context.ExecuteSqlProcedure(sqlparameters, "FINACCJournalInsert");
                return retval;
            }
        }
    }
```

This record is perfectly insert into the table. But always return -1 It does not return count.

Please suggest me where I am going wrong

Comment: what is @JournalID and where is it filled with a value ?

Comment: Please post the actual code, this code will not compile

Comment: I updated my question. I added real code. I have use Journal Table And journal detail table. In journal table is single record will insert and in journal detail multiple record will insert. JournalID is the PK of the journal table and FK of the JournalDetail table. @JournalID is the new ID (which will get after insert in journal table) JournalID is the Autoincrement

Comment: Why are you getting a count from the table where there will only be one row?

Comment: Yes It will return always one. If it return 1 then successfully insert. If it return -2 then error in inserting. It will help me to display message to user that record  successfully insert or not

Comment: can you post the code where you call this procedure and get its result.

Answer (score 0):

Your `try/catch` and `transaction` are inverted from what I usually see in similar situations. Your error handling and commit pattern seem strange as well.

Try this pattern instead:

```
alter procedure dbo.FINACCJournalInsert (
     @Date datetime
   , @FiscalYearID int
   , @PeriodID int
   , @Memo varchar(500)
   , @ProjectID varchar(128)
   , @IsPost bit
   , @IsVoid bit
   , @Amount money
   , @CurrencyCode varchar(3)
   , @CurrencyID int
   , @FINACCJournalDetailBulkInsert dbo.FINACCJournalDetailBulkInsert Readonly
   ) as 
begin;
  set nocount, xact_abort on;
  begin try;
    begin tran;
    declare @JournalID int;
    insert into dbo.FINACCJournal 
            (Date, FiscalYearID, PeriodID, Memo, ProjectID, IsPost, IsVoid, Amount, CurrencyCode, CurrencyID)
    values (@Date,@FiscalYearID,@PeriodID,@Memo,@ProjectID,@IsPost,@IsVoid,@Amount,@CurrencyCode,@CurrencyID);

    set @JournalID = scope_identity();

    insert into dbo.FINACCJournalDetail
           (JournalID, ReferenceID, ReferenceNumber, ReferenceCustomerVendorEmployeID, ReferenceCustomerVendorEmployeName, Debit, Credit)
    select @JournalID, ReferenceID, ReferenceNumber, ReferenceCustomerVendorEmployeID, ReferenceCustomerVendorEmployeName, Debit, Credit 
    from @FINACCJournalDetailBulkInsert;

    commit tran;
  end try
  begin catch;
    if @@trancount > 0 rollback transaction;
    declare @msg nvarchar(2048) = error_message();
    raiserror (@msg, 16, 1);
    return -2;
  end catch;

  select 
      Id
    , DetailCount = count(*)
  from dbo.FINACCJournalDetail
  where ID = @JournalID;

end;
go
```

Reference: [General Pattern for Error Handling - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpgeneralpattern)

Comment: still return -1

Comment: @KirtiZare Double check your object names. You may have a typo somewhere or some other missing Object. Is there more code in your procedure than you have posted?

Comment: can you post the code where you call this procedure and get its result.

Comment: @GuidoG That should probably be a comment on the question instead of this answer.

Comment: @SqlZim He commented on this answer that he still gets a result of -1 while he should be getting 2 values and not just one with -1 So I wondered if there might be something wrong with how he calls the procedure from this answer

Comment: @GuidoG That makes sense.

Comment: I update my question. I added How I am calling the store procedure